# Make a sheet act like a button

Tags: vba, excel

I want the sheet `Administrator` to act like a button but I don't want to go to the actual sheet.

It should open up an UserForm and stay on the active sheet if click on `Administrator`.

[image]

Comment: Okay.  Have you tried anything? Can you show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a public variable `CurrentSheet`, initialize it to `ActiveSheet` in the Workbook_Open event and then in the workbook's `SheetActivate` event either update the value of `CurrentSheet` or switch back to the previous current sheet and show the user form. Something like (in the `Workbook` code sheet):

```
Public CurrentSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Administrator" Then
        CurrentSheet.Activate
        UserForm1.Show
    Else
        Set CurrentSheet = Sh
    End If
End Sub
```

On Edit: To be safe you can also add the following code. This adds a layer of protection if something causes your project to reset after the `Workbook_Open` event. In the original code I was able to generate a crash when I purposely reset the project before activating Administrator.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set CurrentSheet = Sh
End Sub
```

This might render the code in `Workbook_Open` redundant, but personally I would keep it in since I don't like the idea of having uninitialized global variables, even if they will be initialized before I use them. Also -- if the workbook opens *in* Administrator (which might be some error condition) this will guarantee that `CurrentSheet` has a value.